# Multiple Table with pagination and data filter Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use table-editable.js in a single page. I have 3 different tables that gets loaded dynamically by button clicks. However, only in the first load my table gets loaded properly. On other tables, there is no search bar and dropbox at where it should be. I've tried calling TableEditable.init, but it is no use.

```
// my view
    <div class="page-container" style="margin: 5% 5% 2%;">
       <div class="page-content-wrapper">
          <div class="page-content" >
          <h3 class="page-title">
          Sistem Kullanicilari <small>general portlet samples</small>
          </h3>
          <div class="page-bar">
            <ul class="page-breadcrumb">
              <li>
                <%= link_to fa_icon("home", text: "Anasayfa"), current_user, :style => "font-size: 13px;" %> 
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Sistem Kullanicilari</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="flip" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   <div class="note note-success" >
                        <h3> <span class="label label-danger">Doktorlar</span> </h3>
                         <p>
                         buraya tiklayarak doktorlara ulasabilirsiniz.
                      </p>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="flippatient" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   <div class="note note-success" >

                        <h3> <span class="label label-danger">Hastalar</span> </h3>
                         <p>
                         buraya tiklayarak hastalara ulasabilirsiniz.
                      </p>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="flipadmin" style="cursor:pointer;">
                   <div class="note note-success" >
                       <h3>  <span class="label label-danger">Adminler</span> </h3>
                         <p>
                         buraya tiklayarak adminlere ulasabilirsiniz.
                      </p>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row" id="panel">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="portlet box blue">
                      <div class="portlet-title">
                         <div class="caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Doktorlar
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="portlet-body">
                         <div class="table-toolbar">
                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="btn-group">
                                     <%= link_to fa_icon("user-plus", text: "Doktor Ekle"), new_doctor_path, class: "btn green-haze btn-sm "%> 
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="">
                            <thead>
                               <tr>
                                  <th>
                                     #
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     İsim
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     E-mail
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     Düzenle
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     Delete
                                  </th>
                               </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               <% @doctors.each do |doctor| %>
                               <tr>
                                  <td>
                                     <%= doctor[:id] %>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <%= doctor[:name] %>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <%= doctor[:email] %>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                      <%= link_to fa_icon("cog", text: "Düzenle"), edit_doctor_path(doctor[:id]), :style => "padding: 6px 6px; color: #000" %> 
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <%= link_to fa_icon("minus-square", text: "Sil"), doctor_path(doctor[:id]), :style => "padding: 6px 6px; color: #000", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Silmek istedigine emin misin?" } %> 
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                               <% end %>
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row" id="panelpatient">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="portlet box blue">
                      <div class="portlet-title">
                         <div class="caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Doktorlar
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="portlet-body">
                         <div class="table-toolbar">
                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="btn-group">
                                    <%= link_to fa_icon("user-plus", text: "Doktor Ekle"), new_doctor_path, class: "btn green-haze btn-sm "%> 
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
                            <thead>
                               <tr>
                                 <th>
                                       Id
                                     </th>
                                     <th>
                                        Ad
                                     </th>
                                     <th>
                                       E-posta
                                     </th>
                                     <th>
                                        Telefon
                                     </th>
                                     <th>
                                        Şehir
                                     </th>
                                       <th>
                                        Doğum Tarihi
                                     </th> 

                                      <th>
                                        Uyruk
                                     </th>
                                     <th>
                                        Şikayeti
                                     </th>
                                     <th>
                                        Şikayet Tarihi
                                     </th>

                                      <th>
                                        Süreci
                                     </th>
                                  <th>
                                     Düzenle
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     Delete
                                  </th>
                               </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               <% @patients.each do |patient| %>
                               <tr>
                                   <td>
                                        <%= patient[:id] %>
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <%= patient[:name] %>
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <%= patient[:email] %>
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                        <%= patient[:phone] %>
                                     </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <%= patient[:birthplace] %>
                                     </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <%= patient[:birthdate] %>
                                     </td>

                                     <td>
                                        <%= patient[:nationality] %>
                                     </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <%= patient[:complaints] %>
                                     </td>
                                      <td>
                                        <%= patient[:complaintsdate] %>
                                     </td>

                                     <td>
                                        <%= if (patient.progress != nil) then patient.progress[:active_state] end %>
                                     </td>
                                  <td>
                                     Düzenle 
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                      <%= link_to fa_icon("minus-square", text: "Sil"), patient_path(patient[:id]), :style => "padding: 6px 6px; color: #000", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Silmek istedigine emin misin?" } %> 
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                               <% end %>
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row" id="paneladmin">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="portlet box blue">
                      <div class="portlet-title">
                         <div class="caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Adminler
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="portlet-body">
                         <div class="table-toolbar">
                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="btn-group">
                                  <%= link_to fa_icon("user-plus", text: "Admin Ekle"), new_admin_path, class: "btn green-haze btn-sm "%> 
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
                            <thead>
                               <tr>
                                  <th>
                                     #
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     İsim
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     E-mail
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     Düzenle
                                  </th>
                                  <th>
                                     Delete
                                  </th>
                               </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               <% @admins.each do |admin| %>
                               <tr>
                                  <td>
                                     <%= admin[:id] %>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <%= admin[:name] %>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <%= admin[:email] %>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <%= link_to fa_icon("cog", text: "Düzenle"), edit_admin_path(admin[:id]), :style => "padding: 6px 6px; color: #000" %> 
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     Sil 
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
                               <% end %>
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       TableEditable.init();
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
       $(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery.noConflict();
           $("#flip").click(function(){
               $("#panel").slideToggle('slow');
               $("#paneladmin").hide();
               $("#panelpatient").hide();
           });
       });
    </script>
    <script> 
       $(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery.noConflict();
           $("#flippatient").click(function(){
               $("#panelpatient").slideToggle('slow');
               $("#panel").hide();
               $("#paneladmin").hide();

           });
       });
    </script>
    <script> 
       $(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery.noConflict();
           $("#flipadmin").click(function(){
               $("#paneladmin").slideToggle('slow');
               $("#panelpatient").hide();
               $("#panel").hide();


           });
       });
    </script>
    <style> 
       #panel {
       display: none;
       }
       #panelpatient {
       display: none;
       }
       #paneladmin {
       display: none;
       }
    </style>
```

Table-editable.js:

```
// table-editable.js
var TableEditable = function () {

    var handleTable = function () {

        function restoreRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

            for (var i = 0, iLen = jqTds.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                oTable.fnUpdate(aData[i], nRow, i, false);
            }

            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
            jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
            jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
            jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
            jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';
            jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
            jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';
        }

        function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 4, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>', nRow, 5, false);
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        function cancelEditRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 4, false);
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        var table = $('#sample_editable_1');

        var oTable = table.dataTable({

            // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
            // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js). 
            // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed. 
            //"dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",

            "lengthMenu": [
                [5, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            // set the initial value
            "pageLength": 10,

            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ kayıt"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{ // set default column settings
                'orderable': true,
                'targets': [0]
            }, {
                "searchable": true,
                "targets": [0]
            }],
            "order": [
                [0, "asc"]
            ] // set first column as a default sort by asc
        });

        var tableWrapper = $("#sample_editable_1_wrapper");

        tableWrapper.find(".dataTables_length select").select2({
            showSearchInput: false //hide search box with special css class
        }); // initialize select2 dropdown

        var nEditing = null;
        var nNew = false;

        $('#sample_editable_1_new').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (nNew && nEditing) {
                if (confirm("Previose row not saved. Do you want to save it ?")) {
                    saveRow(oTable, nEditing); // save
                    $(nEditing).find("td:first").html("Untitled");
                    nEditing = null;
                    nNew = false;

                } else {
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow(nEditing); // cancel
                    nEditing = null;
                    nNew = false;

                    return;
                }
            }

            var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['', '', '', '', '', '']);
            var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes(aiNew[0]);
            editRow(oTable, nRow);
            nEditing = nRow;
            nNew = true;
        });

        table.on('click', '.delete', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this row ?") == false) {
                return;
            }

            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
            alert("Deleted! Do not forget to do some ajax to sync with backend :)");
        });

        table.on('click', '.cancel', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (nNew) {
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
                nNew = false;
            } else {
                restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
            }
        });

        table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            /* Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on */
            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

            if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
                /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
                restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            } else if (nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save") {
                /* Editing this row and want to save it */a                saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
                alert("Updated! Do not forget to do some ajax to sync with backend :)");
            } else {
                /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            }
        });
    }

    return {


        init: function () {
            handleTable();
        }

    };

}();
```